# flutter-ios EXC_BAD_ACCESS [main.m : 7]

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

I got some random report from firebase crashlytics it could be pretty often lately. It said:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18cf26b00 objc_object::release() + 16
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18cf2738c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 676
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dccd828 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dccd558 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccd8c __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7c68 __CFRunLoopRun + 1880
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
7  GraphicsServices               0x18ff40584 GSEventRunModal + 100
8  UIKitCore                      0x1baed2d40 UIApplicationMain + 212
9  Runner                         0x1012a7d50 main (main.m:7)
10 libdyld.dylib                  0x18d786bb4 start + 4
com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c7ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c737c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccbe8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  Foundation                     0x18e6bd494 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6  Foundation                     0x18e6bd340 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7  UIKitCore                      0x1bafc31f4 <redacted> + 136
8  Foundation                     0x18e7f023c __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
io.flutter.1.ui
0   App                            0x102259c58 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 52312
1   App                            0x102259a84 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 51844
2   App                            0x102362684 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 1136260
3   App                            0x10243ec8c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038924
4   App                            0x102494dc4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2391492
5   App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
6   App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
7   App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
8   App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
9   App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
10  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
11  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
12  App                            0x102494dc4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2391492
13  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
14  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
15  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
16  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
17  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
18  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
19  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
20  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
21  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
22  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
23  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
24  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
25  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
26  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
27  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
28  App                            0x102494dc4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2391492
29  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
30  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
31  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
32  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
33  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
34  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
35  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
36  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
37  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
38  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
39  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
40  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
41  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
42  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
43  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
44  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
45  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
46  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
47  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
48  App                            0x102494dc4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2391492
49  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
50  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
51  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
52  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
53  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
54  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
55  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
56  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
57  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
58  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
59  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
60  App                            0x1024b3464 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2516068
61  App                            0x1024bc108 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2552072
62  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
63  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
64  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
65  App                            0x10261b8cc kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 3991756
66  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
67  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
68  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
69  App                            0x102adea58 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 8985176
70  App                            0x1024bb254 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2548308
71  App                            0x1024f29a4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2775460
72  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
73  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
74  App                            0x102a3076c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 8271724
75  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
76  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
77  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
78  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
79  App                            0x102a344a8 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 8287400
80  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
81  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
82  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
83  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
84  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
85  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
86  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
87  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
88  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
89  App                            0x10243e96c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2038124
90  App                            0x10249a72c kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2414380
91  App                            0x102453168 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2122088
92  App                            0x10243e0ac kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2035884
93  App                            0x10243dae4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2034404
94  App                            0x10243d6c8 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2033352
95  App                            0x1025f6e80 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 3841664
96  App                            0x1025f6aa8 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 3840680
97  App                            0x1025f69a0 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 3840416
98  App                            0x10246d574 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 2229620
99  App                            0x1023e36d4 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 1664724
100 App                            0x10241d048 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 1900616
101 App                            0x102a83970 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 8612208
102 App                            0x102306298 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 758424
103 App                            0x102ade8b0 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 8984752
104 App                            0x102329cd0 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 904400
105 App                            0x102329bd8 kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions + 904152
106 App                            0x10224b20c kDartVmSnapshotInstructions + 12812
107 Flutter                        0x101f761c8 (Missing)
108 Flutter                        0x10205cd7c (Missing)
109 Flutter                        0x101e3ec80 (Missing)
110 Flutter                        0x101bb6744 (Missing)
111 Flutter                        0x101bc71b4 (Missing)
112 Flutter                        0x101bc3f38 (Missing)
113 Flutter                        0x101b83364 (Missing)
114 Flutter                        0x101bd7b64 (Missing)
115 Flutter                        0x101b90b34 (Missing)
116 Flutter                        0x101b91ffc (Missing)
117 CoreFoundation                 0x18dccd828 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
118 CoreFoundation                 0x18dccd558 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
119 CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccd8c __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
120 CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7c68 __CFRunLoopRun + 1880
121 CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
122 Flutter                        0x101b91e88 (Missing)
123 Flutter                        0x101b9169c (Missing)
124 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
125 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
126 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
io.flutter.1.gpu
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c7ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c737c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccbe8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  Flutter                        0x101b91e88 (Missing)
6  Flutter                        0x101b9169c (Missing)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
io.flutter.1.io
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c7ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c737c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccbe8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  Flutter                        0x101b91e88 (Missing)
6  Flutter                        0x101b9169c (Missing)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8d491c kevent + 8
1  Flutter                        0x101e41454 (Missing)
2  Flutter                        0x101e741a4 (Missing)
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8d3b9c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d959100 _pthread_wqthread + 348
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcec start_wqthread + 4
com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  Runner                         0x1013933b0 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4311184304
1  Runner                         0x101393870 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4311185520
2  Runner                         0x1013830c0 CLSHandler + 4311118016
3  Runner                         0x10137e4b0 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4311098544
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8d2f0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d950c88 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18cea04d0 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x19507e9c8 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 104
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x195082abc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 176
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x1950821f0 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 10
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x195083c9c std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer(std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 38
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bce8 start_wqthread + 190
com.google.fira.worker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8d4430 fsync + 8
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e1a6da8 sqlite3_free_table + 67320
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e1b18b0 sqlite3_randomness + 2476
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e1a66c8 sqlite3_free_table + 65560
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e190cac sqlite3_value_text + 23712
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e15c290 sqlite3_finalize + 3672
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e188f00 sqlite3_step + 64964
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e1792ec sqlite3_step + 432
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18e141b88 sqlite3_exec + 336
9  Runner                         0x1014b5c74 -[APMSqliteStore endTransaction] + 4312374388
10 Runner                         0x1014b5934 -[APMSqliteStore performTransaction:] + 4312373556
11 Runner                         0x10148f4b0 -[APMMeasurement writeEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4312216752
12 Runner                         0x10148edb4 -[APMMeasurement handleEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4312214964
13 Runner                         0x1014a2150 __51-[APMScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 4312293712
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7756c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d776484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d71dbd0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d71e718 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 432
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d726eb8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 600
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9590dc _pthread_wqthread + 312
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcec start_wqthread + 4
com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c7ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c737c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccbe8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  CFNetwork                      0x18e2ea00c -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 212
6  Foundation                     0x18e7f023c __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c7ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c737c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccbe8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  WebCore                        0x196b36eec RunWebThread(void*) + 592
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c7ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8c737c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcccbe8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc7a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18dcc71f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  AVFAudio                       0x193cda60c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6  AVFAudio                       0x193d06768 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 88
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95825c _pthread_body + 128
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d9581bc _pthread_start + 48
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcf4 thread_start + 4
com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8d3a68 __unlink + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d8cfa0c unlink + 16
2  libremovefile.dylib            0x18d7b963c __removefile_tree_walker + 496
3  libremovefile.dylib            0x18d7b9a74 removefile + 140
4  Foundation                     0x18e713c70 -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main] + 168
5  Foundation                     0x18e6d3f8c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740
6  Foundation                     0x18e713af0 -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 84
7  Runner                         0x1013ab838 __53-[ANSAnswersController operationsForUncompressedLog:]_block_invoke + 4311283768
8  Foundation                     0x18e7cb93c __103+[__NSOperationInternal _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:changeKind:oldValue:newValue:indexes:context:]_block_invoke.129 + 28
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7756c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d776484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d719490 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 680
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d725a18 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7262c0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95917c _pthread_wqthread + 472
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bcec start_wqthread + 4
Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bce8 start_wqthread + 190
Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18d95bce8 start_wqthread + 190
```

so i check in my project and just found main.m in

Runner > Runner > Supporting Files > main.m

according with error report line 9 its on main. m line 7. In main.m line 7 is :

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I have no idea what is that means. Can anyone explain how it became an error? And what are the solutions to this error? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the full error output to your question

Comment: You can check if one of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+EXC_BAD_ACCESS looks like your problem (also check the 21 closed ones)

Comment: none of them (flutter issue in github) i though. ( why must closed ones not closed twos two is better than one lol)

Comment: another report come with memory address
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000007c80010

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i already update error log post in  crashlytics  to full complete crashlytics error report, and just it

Answer (score 0):

Have you previously update the version of Firebase Flutter plugins that you're using? I found a similar issue in this [post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6734) that it was caused by an update. [Downgrading](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6734#issuecomment-720519319) to the previous version that they're using solved the issue. You can try downgrading the Firebase plugin that you're using or upgrade to the latest version and see if it makes the errors go away on your build.